# I have a carousel displaying 4 images at a time in desktop. I want only one image should displayed at a time in Mobile view

Tags: html, css

I tried a lot in making this as responsive but I was not successful.
How to make this carousel responsive? In mobile only one image should be displayed, in laptop 3 images should be displayed and in desktop 4 images as in the below image.

Carousel displaying in desktop:

[image]

```css
.col-sm-3 {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px  10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.col-xs-12 {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
/* .carousel-indicators {
    float: left;
    display: flex; 
} */

.all {
    padding-top: 15px;
}

img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    height: 145px;
    width: 145px;
}
.carousel-caption {
    color: black;
}
.jumbotron {
    text-align: center;
    color: green;
}

p {
    font-weight: 700;
    color: darkgreen;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <img src="C:/Users/5023/Desktop/Products/blue.png">
        <div class="carousel-caption" style="color: black;">
            <h5>ABC</h5>
            <p>My Paragraph</p>
      </div>
    </div>    
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <img src="C:/Users/5023/Desktop/Products/sblue.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption" style="color: black;">
            <h5>BCD</h5>
            <p>My Paragraph</p>
      </div>
      </div>   
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <img src="C:/Users/5023/Desktop/Products/pink.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption" style="color: black;">
            <h5>CDE</h5>
            <p>My Paragraph</p>
      </div>
      </div>   
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <img src="C:/Users/5023/Desktop/Products/sblue.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption" style="color: black;">
            <h5>DEF</h5>
            <p>My Paragraph</p>
      </div>
      </div>   
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <img src="C:/Users/5023/Desktop/Products/green.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption" style="color: black;">
            <h5>EFG</h5>
            <p>My Paragraph</p>
      </div>
      </div>    
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <img src="C:/Users/5023/Desktop/Products/choco.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption" style="color: black;">
            <h5>FGH</h5>
            <p>My Paragraph</p>
      </div>
      </div>   
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <img src="C:/Users/5023/Desktop/Products/sblue.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption" style="color: black;">
            <h5>GHI</h5>
            <p>My Paragraph</p>
      </div>
      </div>   
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <img src="C:/Users/5023/Desktop/Products/sblue.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption" style="color: black;">
            <h5>HIJ</h5>
            <p>My Paragraph</p>
      </div>
      </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <img src="C:/Users/5023/Desktop/Products/blue.png">
        <div class="carousel-caption" style="color: black;">
            <h5>IJK</h5>
            <p>My Paragraph</p>
      </div>
      </div>    
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <img src="C:/Users/5023/Desktop/Products/pink.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption" style="color: black;">
            <h5>JKL</h5>
            <p>My Paragraph</p>
      </div>
      </div>   
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <img src="C:/Users/5023/Desktop/Products/sblue.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption" style="color: black;">
            <h5>KLM</h5>
            <p>My Paragraph</p>
      </div>
      </div>   
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <img src="C:/Users/5023/Desktop/Products/choco.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption" style="color: black;">
            <h5>LMN</h5>
            <p>My Paragraph</p>
      </div>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap (or something else) or is your CSS the only thing which is applied?

Comment: Using the bootstrap also in the head section. These are the links which I am using in my HTML file <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the head section, I forgot to include these links

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for are media-queries where you can define CSS for specific selectors for a range of screen resolutions. I modified your code (see below).

The most important change here are the media-queries:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .col {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .col {
        width: 25%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    .col {
        width: 20%;
    }
}
```

Full solution below:

```css
.col {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px  10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.carousel-inner {
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
/* .carousel-indicators {
    float: left;
    display: flex; 
} */

.all {
    padding-top: 15px;
}

img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    height: 145px;
    width: 145px;
}
.carousel-caption {
    color: black;
}
.jumbotron {
    text-align: center;
    color: green;
}

p {
    font-weight: 700;
    color: darkgreen;
    background-color: transparent;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .col {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .col {
        width: 25%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    .col {
        width: 20%;
    }
}

These queries say for those specific screen widths. Apply the following style to the elements with the "col" class.
```

```html
<div class="container carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <div class="col">
        <img src="C:/Users/5023/Desktop/Products/blue.png">
        <div class="carousel-caption" style="color: black;">
            <h5>ABC</h5>
            <p>My Paragraph</p>
      </div>
    </div>    
      <div class="col">
        <img src="C:/Users/5023/Desktop/Products/sblue.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption" style="color: black;">
            <h5>BCD</h5>
            <p>My Paragraph</p>
      </div>
      </div>   
      <div class="col">
        <img src="C:/Users/5023/Desktop/Products/pink.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption" style="color: black;">
            <h5>CDE</h5>
            <p>My Paragraph</p>
      </div>
      </div>   
      <div class="col">
        <img src="C:/Users/5023/Desktop/Products/sblue.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption" style="color: black;">
            <h5>DEF</h5>
            <p>My Paragraph</p>
      </div>
      </div>   
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="col">
        <img src="C:/Users/5023/Desktop/Products/green.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption" style="color: black;">
            <h5>EFG</h5>
            <p>My Paragraph</p>
      </div>
      </div>    
      <div class="col">
        <img src="C:/Users/5023/Desktop/Products/choco.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption" style="color: black;">
            <h5>FGH</h5>
            <p>My Paragraph</p>
      </div>
      </div>   
      <div class="col">
        <img src="C:/Users/5023/Desktop/Products/sblue.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption" style="color: black;">
            <h5>GHI</h5>
            <p>My Paragraph</p>
      </div>
      </div>   
      <div class="col">
        <img src="C:/Users/5023/Desktop/Products/sblue.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption" style="color: black;">
            <h5>HIJ</h5>
            <p>My Paragraph</p>
      </div>
      </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="col">
        <img src="C:/Users/5023/Desktop/Products/blue.png">
        <div class="carousel-caption" style="color: black;">
            <h5>IJK</h5>
            <p>My Paragraph</p>
      </div>
      </div>    
      <div class="col">
        <img src="C:/Users/5023/Desktop/Products/pink.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption" style="color: black;">
            <h5>JKL</h5>
            <p>My Paragraph</p>
      </div>
      </div>   
      <div class="col">
        <img src="C:/Users/5023/Desktop/Products/sblue.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption" style="color: black;">
            <h5>KLM</h5>
            <p>My Paragraph</p>
      </div>
      </div>   
      <div class="col">
        <img src="C:/Users/5023/Desktop/Products/choco.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption" style="color: black;">
            <h5>LMN</h5>
            <p>My Paragraph</p>
      </div>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is displaying 3 rows

Comment: I modified the snippet to only show the first row. I did however not implement any code to make the carousel functional. This is just to show you have to achieve the described columns on different screen resolutions.